# How to make a macro that allows the user to choose and open a word file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, openfiledialog

I have an Excel file and I want to have a macro in it that allows the user to choose any Word File and then open this selected file. Is this possible?

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Comment: This might help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161286

Comment: The correct way is to try something, show us what you've tried, and ask about any specific issues you run into.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett im pretty sure you were able to understand what i meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the file, you can use Excel Application's `.GetOpenFilename` method.
The method returns the selected file's full path.

```
Dim oWFile As String
oWFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word File, *.docx")
```

Now to open the file, you need to get/create an instance of Word.
Meaning you have to bind Word to Excel. Sample below

```
Dim oWApp As Word.Application
'~~> get instance if already existing
On Error Resume Next
Set oWApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
'~~> create it otherwise
If oWApp Is Nothing Then Set oWApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'~~> make sure it is visible
oWApp.Visible = True
'~~> Open the word file using the grabbed/created Word Application Object
'~~> and the full file path we get using the .GetOpenFilename method
oWApp.Documents.Open oWFile
```

I used Early Binding where in you need to reference the Microsoft Word Object Library.
To do this, in VBE go to  Tools > References and select 
 Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library (for office 2010).
The number varies depending on the office version.

Answer (score 1):

You are really not that specific but i guess you would have the names of all documents listed in your Excel Cells. In the OnClick Event of that Cell you could then open a word document like this:

```
Sub openWordDocument()

    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")  
    wordapp.documents.Open "C:\Documents\blablabla" & ActiveCell.Value
    wordapp.Visible = True

End Sub
```

You would have to combine the path where you have saved your word files and the name of that specific file, which I assumed you write in your cell.

If you need something else please specify...

Comment: I have a macro on my excel file to paste all tables i have on the excel file to specefic bookmarks on a MS word template. The code I was able to come up with was one where I would choose the file. the problem is that the user may want to update this template. in this case, I`d need the macro code to at the least give the user a dialog box with a list of files within a directory...

Comment: I found this little guide which you can use to get all files in a directory: http://excelexperts.com/vba-tips-list-files-in-a-folder

Comment: If you want this not directly in your cells then you should create a UserForm. With a control like ListBox or ListView you can create the list of all files in that specific directory.

Comment: thanks for your help as well, @oHoodie. The other answer i got solved my problem already :)